# Custom error "webpage not available” in android

Tags: android, titanium

I am having some trouble with connecting to internet while using home WiFi connection. Only the error comes up on the screen that 'Web page not available'.How can i customize this page as soon as possible!

Comment: Please check with some other urls.

Comment: Show some code please!

Comment: did you added the permission in Manifest?

Comment: Have you added Internet permission to your Manifest file???

Comment: Check answer or you can override `onReceivedError` method like [this](http://pastebin.com/PvHrWBuM)

Comment: i like to have a custom and i like to call it in titanum when i try to connect internet some thing like here https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130976/how-can-i-hide-a-webview-when-the-url-gets-a-404-error
i create a file but i am not able to call that file path show as "android_assets/Resources/alloy/controllers/error.html"

Answer (score 0):

You can check network connectivity in `onCreate` before loading webview. If the connectivity is available, load url in a webview, else show custom dialog for **No connection available**.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
    c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (connectivityManager != null) {
    NetworkInfo network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (network.getState() != NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        // record the fact that there is not connection
        isConnectivity = false;
    }
}

if(isConnectivity)
{
    //load url in a webview
}
else
{
    //show custom dialogbox
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for respond my question. but im using titanium http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api

Comment: @maheshrocks okay. please add appropriate tags in your question. :)

Comment: @maheshrocks check [this](http://pastebin.com/uX56brh3) code. That should help :)